Laravel9のAuth0の実装サンプルを使用して機能実装しましたが、401になってします。
設定方法はほぼこの公式ページに習って設定しております。
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/laravel
セッションベースでの認証ガードは、問題なく機能しているようですが、apiでのガードがすべて401になってしまいます。
apiへのアクセス（例えば/api/me)の場合、React側で構築したフロントエンドの方でトークンを発行し、そのトークンでLaravel側のバックエンドにアクセスするという仕組み作っています。有効なトークンを利用していると思っていますが、401にしかならず未だ認証できていません。
% curl --request GET \
  --url http://localhost/api/me \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
  -i

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Host: localhost
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.3.6
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Sun, 12 May 2024 10:15:18 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

{"message":"Unauthenticated."}

リクエストするとこのような形になってしまいます。これはどのようにデバックし解決したらよいでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

curl コマンドの --header オプションで指定している TOKEN の部分を、有効なトークンに置き換える必要があるはずですが、こちらの認識はあっていますか？

はい、その認識です。React側で発行した有効なトークンに置き換える認識です。

そもそもwebページのセッションベースの認証はAuth0で実装されているのですが、トークンベースの認証がチュートリアルの手順でやっても実装されていない気がしています。
